# Unable to switch to frame in Selenium and given the details below in the description

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, iframe, automation

I'm facing a difficulty when changing into frame. When I right click on the page 'This frame' is displayed.  When i see in 'Page source' i cannot find the frame id or name and even i tried with frame index too. But the control is not getting into the frame.

Xpath Used: `//*[@id="j_id0:mainForm:packageDetail:j_id156:pkgName"]`

[Attached the screenshot of 'Elements' tab (F12).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e79TY.png)

Comment: How did you know _...solution for this question..._ can be available _...ASAP..._?

Answer (score 0):

I think, there could be any of the following reason,

1. Check if you have switched to iframe successfully, I don't see iframe in picture. You need not switch to form.
2. There is huge possibility of input element getting visible after clicking on parent ele or some sibling element. So try clicking on ele wrapper first and then sending text.
3. if you are using java then try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ele-id\"]"))` or `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ele-id']"))`. In python it should work.

Provide the webpage url if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see any frame. If you can provide page source screen shot from `body` tag would help more. You can try this.

```
//form[contains(@id, ‘mainForm’)]//input[@class=‘nameInputClass’]
```